# How to setup metronic react theme in laravel

Tags: reactjs, laravel, themes, metronic

I downloaded the metronic template new I want to use react as frontend and laravel as backend. I do not know how to configure both of them to gather.

Comment: please show at least some code about what you have tried

Comment: search for laravel mix react

Answer (score 0):

Metronic use create-react-app try to use this tool https://github.com/mjsarfatti/create-react-app-laravel/ its for adapt output to plucli/index.php